# Tridion 2011 - How to unselect all the default selected publications while adding a group to a user?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am facing one typical issue on Tridion 2011 administrator activity.

> **How to replicate the issue?**

1. Open a User
2. Add a Group to the user
3. Once group is inserted, by default all the publications are checked/ticked

Now here is the issue, if I have 200 publications and in that I want to check/tick only 2 publications then I need to uncheck remaining 198 publications manually.

Which is really difficult task doing for 20-30 users same activity.

I tried by checking and unchecking "ALL PUBLICATIONS" check box but NO LUCK.

> **How to fix this?**

OR

> **Is there any hotfix already available?**

Comment: You really shouldn't be writing what sounds like a support ticket here... If there are hotfixes they are available in Tridion World, check it there first.

Comment: @NunoLinhares: You are right but in the meanwhile to handling this tedious job, i have posted it. To know if there is any quick solution. Now I got a quick solution from **puntero**, which really helps at this point of time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the following workaround:

- Select all publications (Control + A)
- Press Spacebar (Toggles selected/unselected)

Comment: Nice tip! Btw, in Chrome, I had to select at least one publication before Control A would unselect everything. Arrows and space bar also help with quick selection.

Comment: Thanks Puntero. Nice and a quick solution from you.

Answer (score 7):

Typically [I'd recommend setting users to a group specifically for scope and permissions](http://www.createandbreak.net/2012/07/sdl-tridion-authorization.html), rather than trying to define this for each of some 20-30 (or more) users.

For example:

1. **Create "Rights" groups** (or use the defaults) with `This Group will be available for setting permissions in the following Publications:` set to All Publications.
2. **Create "Scope" groups** with membership to one or more rights groups, with the scope limited to certain publications. Use Puntero's useful tip here. *Optionally use separate groups for permissions.*
3. Going forward, **add users to a *Scope* group with** `Membership Scope:` **set to** `All Publications`

This lets you consolidate global user changes to a few groups and simplify manual changes, even if experiencing a possible UI bug.

Comment: Thanks Alvin. Most of groups are handled by setting to all publications, which makes life easier. But we have some groups which we want to specify some specific publications to specific business groups.